# Fork call working

Tags: c, linux, fork

can anybody explain me working of fork in detail

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int i, b;
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    fflush (stdout);
    b = fork ();
    if (b == -1) {
      perror ("error forking");
    }
    else if (b > 0)             //parent process
    {
      wait ();
      printf ("\nparent %d", getpid ());
    }
    else
      printf ("\nchild %d %d", getpid (), getppid ());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

its just i need to know that if fork have same code as parent then this for loop should never stop creating child processes (every child will have its own for loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each child will continue the loop, but the operative word here is "continue". The variable `i` will be inherited by the first child, and then increased, and this increased value is inherited by the second child, etc.

The same will happen in the children, as `i` is inherited and keeps it value from the parent process. This means that the loops will soon end in all children.

Comment: @mrigendra The entire memory of the parent process, including locations (and with that the values) of variables, is copied to the child process.

Comment: so how value of b is changed, in parent if it is pid of child then child should have same value of b .

Comment: nope, `b` is assigned _after_ `fork` returns, and it returns a different value in the parent and child process. However, `b` has the same (uninitialized) value in both parent and child at the point they fork, before the call returns.

Comment: and do values in other childs have any effect on there parents, like if i =1 in child then its parent version of i is also updated to 1?

Comment: @mrigendra No, the inheritance only goes "downward", once a parent has created a child, they are completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

When you `fork`, the child process will continue with the same next instruction as the parent one and the values.

So it will stop one day ;)

Take a look at a similar question : [fork in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256357/fork-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Yes although the parent and child code are the same but in parent the fork returns the child process id hence in parents code, the variable b contains the child's pid whereas the in child, the fork returns 0, hence in the child code segment the variable b will have 0 and so does we can achieve different jobs even though forking will have same parent code in child.